# If $A\subset \Bbb{R} $ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$, then $A$ is infinite? If A is infinite, then is dense? If #$A=$#$\Bbb{R}$, then $A$ is dense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I need someone to criticize my answers. I'm not so sure about them.

1)
$A$ is dense, then $A$ is infinite

$A$ is dense if for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $x$ is the limit point of a sequence that lives in $A$ and a convergent sequence sequence has infinite points.

2) $A$ is infinite, then is dense

$A=(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$ is infinite, but is not dense in $\Bbb{R}$ because given $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$, exits an open ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\cap A=\emptyset$

3)  If #$A=$#$\Bbb{R}$, then $A$ is dense?

It just says to me that $A$ has the same number of members of $\Bbb{R}$, nothing more, so i can't even begin the question.

Comment: $|(0,1)|=|\mathbb{R}|$. Also Convergent sequences do not need to have infinitely many points, since they can be eventually constant. Instead, why don't you just calculate the closure of a finite set?

Comment: Finite sets can not be dense in $\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not true that a convergent has to have infinitely many points: the constant sequence $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$ converges to $1$ and has only one distinct points, namely, $1$ itself. The characterization of *dense* that you’re using here is not the easiest one from which to prove that $A$ must be infinite. Here are two easier approaches:

- If $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, then $\operatorname{cl}A=\Bbb R$. Every finite subset of $\Bbb R$ is closed, so if $A$ is finite, then $\operatorname{cl}A=A$, which certainly isn’t equal to $\Bbb R$. Thus, $A$ must be infinite.
- If $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, then every non-empty open set in $\Bbb R$ contains at least one point of $A$. If $A$ is finite, $A$ has a largest element, say $a$. Then $(a,a+1)$ is a non-empty open set in $\Bbb R$ that contains no point of $A$, so $A$ cannot be dense in $\Bbb R$.

You *can* use the sequence characterization, but you’d have to prove that if $A$ is finite, and $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $A$ that is convergent, then there are an $m\in\Bbb N$ and an $a\in A$ such that $x_n=a$ for each $n\ge m$ (i.e., the sequence is *eventually constant*). In that case it converges to $a$, so the only possible limits of convergent sequences in $A$ are the points of $A$.

Your answer to $(2)$ is fine.

For $(3)$, just observe that $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$ and is clearly not dense in $\Bbb R$. For that matter, you could use your example from $(2)$.

Comment: A sequence eventually constant (as a constant sequence) define a isolated point, not a limit point (in metric spaces). Correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: @Masacroso: An eventually constant sequence in any topological space, metrizable or not, converges to the point at which it is eventually constant. That point need not be isolated. In $\Bbb R$, for instance, the sequence $\langle 1,1,1\ldots\rangle$ converges to $1$, and $1$ is not an isolated point of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: But $1$ is not a limit point cause the constant sequence, it is a limit point cause exist some not constant sequence that converge to it. Of course in $\Bbb R$ all points are limits points, but in any other space (or subspace) it is misleading to characterize a limit point from any kind of convergent sequence. Indeed if this will be true then isolated points cannot exist.

Comment: @Masacroso: I suspect that you’re being confused by the fact that the word *limit* means two somewhat different things in *limit of a sequence* and *limit (point) of a set*. The point $1$ in $\Bbb R$ is not a limit point of the set $\{1\}$: that set has no limit points. It *is*, however, the limit of the sequence $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$ of points in the set $\{1\}$. We don’t characterize limit points of a set $A$ as limits of sequences from $A$, even in metric spaces; we characterize points in the closure of $A$ as limits of sequences from $A$, and points in the closure of $A$ are ...

Comment: ... not necessarily limit points of $A$. And none of this discussion is relevant to the OP’s question.

Comment: I dont understand why you says this is not relevant. What is the point to talk about sequences if is not to characterize limit points?

Comment: @Masacroso: The point is that in a metric space $X$ one can characterize denseness as follows: $A$ is dense in $X$ if and only if each point of $X$ is the limit of a convergent sequence of points of $A$. **This is not the same as saying that every point of** $X$ **is a limit point of** $A$, and it’s not true that $A$ is dense in $X$ if and only if each point of $X$ is a limit point of the set $A$.

Comment: Oh, ok... I understand. I dont knew this characterization so I assumed that when you were talking about sequences you were talking about limit points. Yes I knew that not all points need to be limit points. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Masacroso: You’re welcome. It’s not a characterization that I like much, since it’s not applicable to topological spaces in general and is usually not the easiest one to use even when it *is* applicable. It holds for all [Fréchet-Urysohn space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Fr.C3.A9chet.E2.80.93Urysohn_space), hence for all first countable spaces (and of course then for all metric spaces).

Comment: I loved the answer and the discussion. I think it is aggrandizing to the topic since the difference debated is a very pertinent question. Thankyou so much!

Comment: @Lucas: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Too complicated.:)

1)  Yes, by contrapositive: a bounded set cannot be dense in ${\bf R}$, and a finite set is necessarily bounded.

2)  The infinite set $]0, 1[$ is bounded, hence cannot be dense in ${\bf R}$.

3)  The set $]0, 1[$ is equipotent with ${\bf R}$, yet (by 2)) is not dense in ${\bf R}$.

Comment: Your answer helped me to understand in a very easy way. Thankyou, but, indeed, i cannto show this answers to my professor lol
He would ask: "but why....?"

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  Well, the only "whys" your professor could ask are these two: (i) why can a bounded set never be dense in ${\bf R}$, and (ii) why $]0, 1[$ is equipotent to ${\bf R}$.  Address these, and your professor should accept.

To address (i), it is sufficient to note that ${\bf R}$ has a point that is at least distance $1$ (or $10^6$) away from the bounded set, hence cannot be approximated by elements of that set.

To address (ii), a bijection from ${\bf R}$ to $]0, 1[$ is given by appropriately shifting and scaling the principal branch of $\atan$.)

Comment: Oh! Super! I got it. Both answers. In the first, i took a time to imagine, but in the second i realized instantly that there's a bijection from R to (-1,1) which is the arctg(x). So simple, but my head is a mass with so much information in this discipline. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to 2 answers 3 as well. As for 1, you need to specifically pick an $x\notin A$. Once you do that, your argument works.

Comment: About my argument in 1), i did't thought about it. What you spoke helps a lot, man! Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

For (1), note that the integers are a subset of the reals. Therefore, any dense subset of the reals needs to have at least one point in each of the unit balls centred at each integer.

As Arthur points out, your argument in (2) is correct and also works to disprove (3).